# need help making html(with js) chat application online

Tags: javascript, html, chat, multiplayer

currently making a chat application with my friend that we intended on making online, after we made the chat system itself we wearnt actually sure how to make it online. we tried countless things but nothing worked

can somebody experienced with this help us?? im willing to pay for servers if i need to, im just wondering how i can make it online at all

the code if you want to review it, we are beginners so ignore the sloppyness:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title ng-bind="app.pageTitle">Immuno Chat</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Logo.ico" />
  <script>
    var username = prompt("Enter Username");
    while (username == null || username.trim() == "") {
      username = prompt("Enter Username");
    }
    username = username.trim();
    while (username.length < 3 || username.length > 20) {
      username = prompt("Enter Username");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function enter() {
      var message = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
      if (message.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
        document.getElementById("textbox").value = "";
        document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='chatmessage' style='font-size:20px;'>" + "<b>[" + username + "]: </b>" + message + "<span style='color:grey;'> [" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[0] + ":" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[1] + "]</span></div>" + document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML;
        if (message.includes("CMD 0") && (username.toLowerCase() == "yal" || username.toLowerCase() == "substics")) {
          var num = message.split(" ")[2] || 1; 
          if (num > 50) {
            num = 50;
          }
          for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            nuclearWarhead();
          }
        }
        if (message.includes("CMD 1") && (username.toLowerCase() == "yal" || username.toLowerCase() == "substics")) {
          var num = message.split(" ")[2] || 1;
          if (num > 50) {
            num = 50;
          }
          for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            joe();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function joe() {
      document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='chatmessage' style='font-size:20px;'>" + "<b>[Joe]: </b>" + "JOE" + "<span style='color:grey;'> [" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[0] + ":" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[1] + "]</span></div>" + document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML;
      setTimeout(function() {joe()}, 5000);
    }
    
    function nuclearWarhead() {
      var countdown = 10;
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (countdown == 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='chatmessage' style='font-size:20px;'>" + "<b>[Nuclear Warhead]: </b>" + "<span style='color:red;'>BOOM</span>" + "<span style='color:grey;'> [" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[0] + ":" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(":")[1] + "]</span></div>";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "<div class='chatmessage' style='font-size:20px;'>" + "<b>[Nuclear Warhead]: </b>" + countdown + "</div>" + document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML;
          countdown--;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>

  <center>
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none">Immuno Chat</h1>
  
    <p style="font-family: Helvetica">Your Username is:
      <script>document.write(username)</script></p>

    <hr style="border:1px solid black">
  </center>
  
  <input type="text" name="name" id="textbox" value="" autocomplete="off" style="position:fixed;width:60%;font-size:20px;z-index:1;bottom:15px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;left:0;right:0;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) enter();">

  <div id="chat" style="position:absolute;top:30%;z-index:0;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tried some php stuff but idk how to do that so it didnt work

Comment: You need an application server.

Comment: sorry im not sure what an application server is or how to get it, can you be more specific?

Comment: You have to write code for the backend, an application that runs on the server. The frontend is the client that connects to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

All of this code is client-side, so the messages you send to the chat aren't actually sent anywhere, they're just in your browser. To get it online and working you need a server and a database.

Comment: how do i connect a server to my code?